# Huge amount of undefined references when compiling pjsip / pjsua samples

Tags: compiling

On an ubuntu 15.10 VM I've installed [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org) so that I can work to create a very small soft phone for testing a virtual voip network.

The package includes some sample code in `pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/src/samples`.

When trying to compile the code using g++ or gcc I get screen full of `undefined reference` (sample below after running `g++ pjsua2_demo.cpp -o pjsua2_demo`).

Maybe a path issue?

@witsend
Thanks.

```
/tmp/ccsTUqc5.o: In function \`MyCall::onCallState(pj::OnCallStateParam&)':
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to \`pj::Call::getInfo() const'
/tmp/ccsTUqc5.o: In function \`mainProg1(pj::Endpoint&)':
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to \`pj::Endpoint::libInit(pj::EpConfig const&)'
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to \`pj::TransportConfig::TransportConfig()'
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to \`pj::Endpoint::transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e, pj::TransportConfig const&)'
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to \`pj::Endpoint::libStart()'
pjsua2_demo.cpp:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to \`pj::AccountConfig::AccountConfig()'
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your g++ command line does not actually link any of the libraries that you just installed: try

```
g++ pjsua2_demo.cpp -o pjsua2_demo `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`
```

See [Building Application using PJSIP with GNU Tools](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting_Started_Using)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Wouldn't that happen on its own based on the `#includes <*.h>`?

Comment: Header files just provide declarations of the objects for the compiler: to actually link the objects to form an executable program, you need to tell the linker where to find the libraries themselves: see [Compiling and Linking](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html) for example

Comment: Alright so that worked. I used the same thing to compile some of their samples in C and that worked as well (using gcc instead of g++). I'm still kind of baffled though. I understand the concept of linking from the link you gave me, but all through my software engineering degree, I don't remember ever explicitly having to tell the compiler to do that. Is it possible that gcc and g++ need that specified, and some other compilers will do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much pilot6
in my case I solve it as the following
"g++ op.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpjproject.pc`"